# mysql select to check lottery ticket combination

Tags: php, mysql

I spent the last night trying different mysql queries to simply check lottery combination using mysql/php but still not able to make it work fine! Google gives many attempts by users, especially here in stackoverflow, nothing found that can help all the way..

I have a table with all previous winner numbers, i simply want to check 5 main numbers and 2 extra numbers to point out any winning happened earlier for the given numbers

table name: win_archive (9 columns)
table structure:

```
 id | main_b1 | main_b2 | main_b3 | main_b4 | main_b5 | extra_b1 | extra_b2 | win_date
 1 .   22 | 10  |  5 | 59 | . 61 . |   1 |  9 . | 2/1/2011
 2 .   43 | 23  |  11 | 76 | . 25 . |   13 |  9 . | 30/3/2015
 3. ...
```

Tried to use mysql IN clause

```
SELECT id, 
   main_b1, 
   main_b2, 
   main_b3, 
   main_b4, 
   main_b5, 
   extra_b1, 
   extra_b2, 
   win_date 
   WHERE  main_b1 IN ( 21, 44, 55, 22, 11, 1, 4 )
```

didn't work if there is more than 1 number then i can't check them, also we have the extra balls are different set than main balls, which means there maybe the same number in the combination but- like one in main balls set and one within the extra 2...

expecting to give 5+2 numbers to a php then by this mysql query to have something like:

**Case A:** Matching 2 main balls: 3 wins found in archive

- date: line was: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-y-y
- date: line was: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-y-y
- date: line was: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-y-y

**Case B:** Matching 2 main balls and 1 extra balls: 1 win found in archive

- date: line was: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-y-y

**Case C:** Matching 3 main balls and 2 extra balls: 1 win found

- date: line was: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-y-y

Is it really complicated? there are hundreds of sites online can check the lottery ticket combinations, thought the check/query will be all over..

Any hints will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Do you want to find all combinations of previously matched balls (starting with 2 main and going upwards to 5 main and 2 extra)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sample query that I think will achieve what you want. You just need to change the values in the `IN` expressions according to the result you want to search for:

```
SELECT 
   main_b1, main_b2, main_b3, main_b4, main_b5, extra_b1, extra_b2,
   ((main_b1 IN (22, 23, 10, 11, 76)) +
    (main_b2 IN (22, 23, 10, 11, 76)) +
    (main_b3 IN (22, 23, 10, 11, 76)) +
    (main_b4 IN (22, 23, 10, 11, 76)) +
    (main_b5 IN (22, 23, 10, 11, 76))) AS main,
   ((extra_b1 IN (5, 9)) +
    (extra_b2 IN (5, 9))) AS extra,
    win_date
FROM win_archives
HAVING main >= 3 OR main = 2 AND extra > 0
ORDER BY main DESC, extra DESC, win_date DESC
```

I created a bit more sample data in this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e372/8):

```
INSERT INTO win_archives
    (`id`, `main_b1`, `main_b2`, `main_b3`, `main_b4`, `main_b5`, `extra_b1`, `extra_b2`, `win_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 22, 10, 5, 59, 61, 1, 9, '2011-01-02'),
    (2, 43, 23, 11, 76, 25, 13, 9, '2015-03-30'),
    (3, 22, 10, 5, 76, 61, 1, 4, '2014-06-02'),
    (4, 43, 9, 11, 76, 25, 5, 9, '2012-08-07'),
    (5, 22, 10, 5, 59, 61, 5, 12, '2016-12-02'),
    (6, 22, 23, 11, 76, 10, 5, 6, '2017-07-19'),
    (7, 22, 10, 5, 59, 61, 1, 9, '2018-09-02'),
    (8, 43, 23, 11, 76, 22, 13, 8, '2005-04-11')
;
```

With this sample data the output is:

```
main_b1 main_b2 main_b3 main_b4 main_b5 extra_b1 extra_b2 main  extra   win_date
22      23      11      76      10      5        6        5     1       2017-07-19
43      23      11      76      22      13       8        4     0       2005-04-11
43      23      11      76      25      13       9        3     1       2015-03-30
22      10      5       76      61      1        4        3     0       2014-06-02
43      9       11      76      25      5        9        2     2       2012-08-07
22      10      5       59      61      1        9        2     1       2018-09-02
22      10      5       59      61      5        12       2     1       2016-12-02
22      10      5       59      61      1        9        2     1       2011-01-02
```

Comment: Great Nick, this works, I relized something, if the lines are too much, I can't distinguish the numbers... is there a way to colorize (simple html color code) those matching numbers in the same line... just a thought to improve the output.. thanks again

Comment: Never mind, i managed it through php output using html colors.. thanks Nick

Comment: Hi Mike if this did answer your question I'd appreciate it if you could mark it accepted. Thanks

Comment: I did.. actually didn't notice that, thought its only the vote :) thanks Nick

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

A normalised schema might look something like this:

Draw

```
draw_id | date
      1 | 2011-01-02
      2 | 2015-03-30
```

Draw_detail

```
draw_id | ball_ord | ball_number
      1 |         1 |         22
      1 |         2 |         10
    Etc...
      2 |         1 |         43 
      2 |         2 |         23
     ....
```

Comment: Hi Strawberry, didn't understand what you mean but Nick above has nailed it actually, that is what I wanted, I just want to improve the outcome to colorize the matching numbers, perhaps in an elegant table and so.. thanks for your time.

Comment: @Mike Yes, but normalisation is fundamental to efficient database design. If you're able to restructure your schema along the lines described above, the likelihood is that your queries will be much faster (and simpler) - especially on large data sets.